# Paste code from clipboard in multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I was looking for Vanilla Javascript solution, of copy paste code into multiple input fields.

i have got solutions on internet but are jQuery based.
[This was jQuery Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804064/pasting-multiple-numbers-over-multiple-input-fields)

```
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
```

I had copy this code from email, and past code on any input field, it will paste complete code one by one in each field. Then get this code verify with pre-saved code.
Pasting and then collecting and verify code in **vanilla JavaScript** is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, it can easily be modified to work on specific text inputs, but as-is this ensures every text input on the page gets the same data from the clipboard.

Side note: `querySelectorAll` returns a `nodelist` instead of an array, you can use `[].forEach.call` to use an Array's `forEach` method in a `nodelist`.

```js
// Listen to paste on the document
document.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
  // if the target is a text input
  if (e.target.type === "text") {
   var data = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
   // split clipboard text into single characters
   data = data.split('');
   // find all other text inputs
   [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]"), (node, index) => {
      // And set input value to the relative character
      node.value = data[index];
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
<input type="text" maxlength="1">
```

Comment: i think my query was not clear or you might misunderstood, but i want to paste code like, first digit in first field, 2nd digit in second and so on. 
your current code paste complete code in all fields. Regards :)

Comment: @ArslanAmeer - I've updated the code per your comment - it's now splitting the array and putting one character per input.

Comment: that is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: and for the second part, in which i wanted to get all numbers from input field, make them one code and compare with already save code? or can print on button click.
do i have to apply same iteration again like you did?

Comment: If you've got the data there in that function, you can store it to a hidden input field - or maybe you can try naming the inputs with an array like `<input name="code[]" ...>` play around and see what you can come up with.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, using hidden input field and paste complete code there for verification.  Thanks A lot :)

Comment: Any chance to remove undefined for empty fields?

Comment: just add data[index] ||= ''; before  node.value = data[index]; @mistersholmes