# Paste Into More Than One Bootstrap 5 Input?

Tags: google-apps-script, bootstrap-5

I've used Bootstrap 5 in Google Sheets to make a Userform (Custom Menu > Open Form). I'm very new to this.

In my Google Sheet Userform, I have 7 places to input Phone Numbers. In the image below, I copied 7 rows of phone numbers from another document. (Each phone number is below the other on the document). But when selecting paste, they all go into the same input bar.

Is it possible, with code, to select paste and each phone number pastes into a SEPARATE input bar, instead of all into the same one?

It would greatly speed up my workflow if so. If not, no worries. At least I would know. Hope I explained it clearly, but please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Here's my Google Sheet (Custom Menu > Open Form):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZzSxk6khqwYN2CylMTmgKtJXgcilM7nJVINWqrkWGSg/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: @Rubén Sorry about that. I fixed the post to make it more self-contained.

Comment: It's unclear what is being asked.

Comment: @Rubén I'll try my best to clear it up.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60939532/1595451

Comment: Thank you for the reference @Rubén. With this solution I can place a specific amount of characters in each input bar but I can't figure out how to make it add a full phrase before the line break in each input bar (for example, some numbers might be longer and some shorter). But the reference has me on the right track. I'll keep doing research.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show what you tried to adapt the solution from the referred question to your needs.