# How to go about monitoring copy and paste in windows

Tags: c#, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [copy/paste event listener in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156975/copy-paste-event-listener-in-c-sharp)

I'm trying to write a small windows service which monitors and logs whenever a file or anything is copied from the system. I really don't have any idea of how to go about this. I need suggestions or some direction or links about where to go about looking for this. I will be using C#.

Comment: @HarisHasan thnks for the link