# Pasting into multiple text boxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, copy-paste

I have a .net application which includes search screen which has a panel with has **three text boxes**, each with a varying character lengths.

What I'd like to do is **capture** when the **paste command** when **invoked** from the first box and paste my clipboard into the three boxes.

This functionality is similar to many modern applications accepting input for serial keys and phone numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156975/copy-paste-event-listener-in-c-sharp

Comment: You want to capture when the paste command is invoked? Not capture on the copy command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can find there is no other sensible way of doing this than to capture the WM_PASTE event.

Derive a class from TexBox and implement this method:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

class TextBoxWithOnPaste : TextBox
{

    public delegate void PastedEventHandler();

    [Category("Action")]
    [Description("Fires when text from the clipboard is pasted.")]
    public event PastedEventHandler OnPaste;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x302 && OnPaste != null) // process WM_PASTE only if the event has been subscribed to
        {
            OnPaste();
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Then put three of those custom controls on your form, and assign the `OnPaste` event on all three textboxes to the same method, in this case I called it `textPasted()`:

```
private void textPasted()
{
    String input = Clipboard.GetText();

    int l1 = textBoxWithOnPaste1.MaxLength;
    int l2 = textBoxWithOnPaste2.MaxLength;
    int l3 = textBoxWithOnPaste3.MaxLength;

    try
    {
        textBoxWithOnPaste1.Text = input.Substring(0, l1);
        textBoxWithOnPaste2.Text = input.Substring(l1, l2);
        textBoxWithOnPaste3.Text = input.Substring(l2, l3);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }

}
```

Since you implied "like a serial", I guessed you want the pasted string to be split among the textboxes. The code above is not perfect for that (try pasting a single space into the third text box after entering data manually in all three, so it would be nice if you knew in which textbox the text was pasted, for example by altering the event's parameters and that way sending the sender with it), but it basically works and I guess you can figure out the rest (you could use the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property to identify the textbox).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Follow up question is why do you say it's the only sensible answer?  Will it capture both the Ctrl+V, Context Paste and Edit --> Paste?  

Seems like there's a lot of ways to do it; even the one proposed above by Mr. James Hill appears to be less work.

Comment: @amadib it's the only logical thing to do, because while capturing Cltr+V you won't get notified when the user selects Paste from the context menu, and if you also go and capture mouse clicks it's becoming a maintenance hell quite quickly. Furthermore, JamesHill's code can't simply be placed on a form: a form won't process the WM_PASTE message. [Edit controls and combo boxes do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649028(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Capture the paste event:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    // Did paste occur?
    if (m.Msg == 0x302) {
        //Paste occurred, add your logic here
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Then, access the [Clipboard object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to get the desired text.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind key down event, and when you get `Ctrl + V` or `Ctrl + v`, you update the value of the three textbox with value in the clipboad. You can do this on `TextChanged` event off first text box.

Comment: What about selecting Paste from the context menu?

Comment: In that case Text_Change event will be fired, if you use context menu.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the captured text
`String txt = Clipboard.GetText();`
and place it in the "Text" property of the other textbox

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the character limit of the boxes and register for `TextChanged` and if the pasted (or typed) text is longer jump/cut to the next `TextBox`.

Comment: how to know if it is pasted text or not on textchanged?