# Pasting multi-line text in to single line textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a single line textbox, when I copy some text from lets say notepad that is on multiple lines and paste them in to my text box, only the first line of text appears (thats obvious) but how can I change this so that the lines are joined automatically upon pasting them and separated by a space. I see that I would need to modify the textbox_changed event but this would affect everything that goes on in that textbox not only the paste event. Could you provide me with some code to handle a paste event and ignore all other events.. thanks :)

```
winforms
mouse paste event
```

Comment: What interface are you referring to WPF, WinForms, Webpage?

Comment: step 1.  use the debugger, put a breakpoint at the beginning of your text changed event and see what's there

Comment: sounds like he looking for string.Join() method.. but I could be mistaken..

Comment: You could find something useful in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971862/pasting-into-multiple-text-boxes

Comment: are you trying to identify when a paste event happens inside a single-line textbox so you can append the pasted text to the end of the existing text instead of them pasting their text whereever they want?

Answer (score 3):

is [this](http://www.vcskicks.com/clipboard-textbox.php) what you're looking for?

*Clipboard Events
A Textbox in C# has a number of useful events to indicate when certain actions have been taken. For example, .NET textboxes have an event to indicate when the text has changed or when the user has pressed a key. These events allow C# developers to write clean code that interacts with textboxes.
Following the same principles, we can manually implement events that are triggered by clipboard actions, i.e. text is cut, copied, or pasted in the textbox. The .NET Framework does not come with these events, but they are not difficult to implement.
7/5/11 Update: Added support to suppress copy, cut, and paste events.
Custom Textbox
To implement custom events, we are going to have to create our own textbox user control. The user control will inherit the Textbox class since we want all the default behaviors of a .NET textbox.
Creating a custom user control will also let us override the WndProc function, which processes messages passed to the control. By overriding the function, we can detect messages such as when text is cut, copied, or pasted, before allowing the control to process them.*

Comment: would be nice if they gave a real example, seems like a guessing game where i'm supposed to put this code

Comment: you're making a custom user control instead of using the Windows textbox control. You put the code in the new user control.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .asp webforms you need to change the text mode in your textbox

to SOMETHING LIKE THIS `TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50" Rows="5"`

in Winforms

```
 textBox1.Multiline = true;
```

Comment: you answered a question that the OP wasn't asking

Comment: "how can I change this so that the lines are joined automatically upon pasting them"

Comment: and why do you thik if he is using a textbox which changes to textarea is wrong

Comment: Because it doesn't `automatically upon pasting them and separated by a space`.  at least not without extra work

Comment: He was clearly asking how to paste multiline text into a single line textbox... I don't think an option is for him to change his single line textbox.

Comment: He is asking how can he copy some stuff from the let say notepad to the textbox so he is not loosing lines typically in a single line textbox you lose one line

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it's a winforms application and yes I will be using the string.join method once i detect the mouse paste event

Comment: @ace007 if all you need is to wrap line just like in notepad why not use muliline

Comment: @COLDTOLD i dont know how to explain this but that's not an option it simply wont work in my application. I have changed my textbox to a multiline but still I need to detect the mouse paste event so that I can join the lines in to a single line separated by a space. onjly this way I can process the text to my needs.

Comment: @ace007 take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446233/hook-on-default-paste-event-of-winforms-textbox-control

Comment: @COLDTOLD his code makes no sense to me, he uses private void Main() yet that's not a winforms load event and its not invoked when the form is loaded looks almost like a console app load event. Also when I change it to a form_load event I have an error saying the "sender" variable cant be used because it will give a different meaning to another sender object thats in the forms load event.. so where am I supposed to paste the code he has given :/

Comment: @COLDTOLD Ok i figured out how to use his code, apart from it destroys my form by overwriting it and creating its own new form: "var form = new Form();"