# COPY, CUT, PASTE, DELETE EVENT

Tags: c#, events

I'm developing some software that needs to know when the COPY, CUT, PASTE, DELETE EVENT's

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
     switch ((Win32.Msgs)m.Msg)
        {
            case Win32.Msgs.WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                ...
            case Win32.Msgs.WM_COMMAND:
                ...
            var xy = IntPtr.Size == 8 ? (int)m.WParam.ToInt64() : m.WParam.ToInt32();
                int x = unchecked((short)xy);

            //  MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());

             case IDM_CUT:
             case IDM_COPY:
             case IDM_PASTE:
```

but I can't get event Cut, copy, delete. When I show m.WParam.To.INT32in the first build. I made a table to compare events but it changes when I rebuild.
  How can I have unchange value of m.WParam to compare with my table ? So I just want to recognize COPY, PASTE, CUT EVENT.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you provide more details about what you mean by `m.WParam.To.INT32 is not a const when I build` and `How cant I have unchange value of m.WParam to compare with my const`?

Comment: so sorry about my question.my english doesn't good. when I show m.WParam.ToInt32() I can have value of CUT, COPY event..... but when I rebuild -  this value change, and i don't know real value of Cut, copy, paste event =====>>>>> I just want to know HOW CAN I GET CUT, COPY, PASTE EVENT. HOW RECOGNIZE THIS ? HOW  process this ? please help me :( Thank you.

Comment: This is the way it is done in a C program, IDM_xxx are arbitrary numbers that were selected by the C programmer when he wrote his program.  Typically they are numbered menu commands.  It is not the way it is done in a Winforms program.  You left no breadcrumbs to guess what that Winforms project looks like.

Comment: I think this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1157043/571881