# Detect when paste event ocured in whole system

Tags: c#, windows

I need to detect when some paste something in whole system. For example in notepad or word not only in C# application. Examples I find describe only some WinForms application.

When I will be able to detect that event I would like to modify pasted value.

Thanks

Comment: This, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240328/how-to-hook-a-global-paste-event, may have some helpful information.

Comment: you have to look into Win32 API to achieve this

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you are asking, you will have to inject your application in all the other windows running on the system.  That process is called a Hook.

Excerpt from [How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318804/)

**Global hooks are not supported in the .NET Framework**

> Except for the WH_KEYBOARD_LL low-level hook and the WH_MOUSE_LL low-level hook, you cannot implement global hooks in the Microsoft .NET Framework. To install a global hook, a hook must have a native DLL export to inject itself in another process that requires a valid, consistent function to call into. This behavior requires a DLL export. The .NET Framework does not support DLL exports. Managed code has no concept of a consistent value for a function pointer because these function pointers are proxies that are built dynamically.
>   Low-level hook procedures are called on the thread that installed the hook. Low-level hooks do not require that the hook procedure be implemented in a DLL.

What are [Hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589(VS.85).aspx):

> A hook is a point in the system message-handling mechanism where an application can install a subroutine to monitor the message traffic in the system and process certain types of messages before they reach the target window procedure.

Comment: "Excerpt from How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET"  This link is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should hook to WM_PASTE system event. Achieve this by registering WindowProc callback function

WM_PASTE message https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

WindowProc callback function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This should work

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        // WM_PASTE
        case (0x0302):
            // You can interrupt here, interept or pass by. Do what You need
            MessageBox.Show("PASTE");
            break;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Please respond if this worked for You

Comment: This code will only work for messages pumped to application message queue.  Not messages from other applications on the system.